# Import config from sphinx subfolder

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've created a sphinx project in a subfolder ("docs") inside my project root. When I run the make file autodoc  it cannot find the config file and raises errors.

Is there a way to resolve this?

[project structure](https://www.syshell.net/extra_upload/37608030/project_structure.txt)

[conf.py](https://www.syshell.net/extra_upload/37608030/conf.py)

[Makefile](https://www.syshell.net/extra_upload/37608030/Makefile)

[myreplicator.py](https://www.syshell.net/extra_upload/37608030/myreplicator.py)

[myreplicator.rst](https://www.syshell.net/extra_upload/37608030/myreplicator.rst)

This is the error:

```
/vagrant/python/mymongo/doc/myreplicator.rst:4: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'myreplicator'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/venv/mymongo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx    /ext/autodoc.py", line 518, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/vagrant/python/mymongo/myreplicator.py", line 20, in <module>
logging.config.fileConfig('conf/logging.conf')
  File "/opt/py35/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "/opt/py35/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "/opt/py35/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 956, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

Thanks,
Giovanni

Comment: You should show project structure, code/makefile and actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I have to your folder structure diagram looks very messy.

Well, so from what I can see, there are two possible reasons.

#### 1. System PATH

You didn't put the directory of `myreplicator.py` into the `sys.path` so that the `sphinx.autodoc.py` cannot locate your module (since it will only search the module in system path. Therefore you need to insert your project folder into the `sys.path` first). Which can be done by including the following in `conf.py`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../')) # based on what I see in your structure, the myrepicator.py is in the parent directory of conf.py
```

#### 2. Third-party Pacakge

Inside the `myreplicator.py`, there are some third-party modules cannot be loaded, most likely some C type libs (like `.pyd`). In this case, you can mock those third-party modules which cannot be imported by using below codes

```
from mock import MagicMock, Mock  # if you are using python2
# from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock # if you are using python3

class Mock(MagicMock):
    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
            return Mock()

MOCK_MODULES = ['mymongolib ', 'numpy', 'pandas'] # packages you want to mock
sys.modules.update((mod_name, Mock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)
```

However, from the exception you post, the chance of this error is small.

Overall, I think most likely the error is due to the first reason.